# Monorepo of react native cli and react working - modules not exist in the haste module | YarnWorkspace

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, node-modules, symlink

I  am creating the monorepo with react native clic and react js.

[image]

I am facing the below error , though i dont face any issue with build as its successful.
[image]

I am using Wml An alternative to symlinks that actually copies changed files from source to destination folders.

I am adding

```
 "workspaces": {
    "nohoist": [
      "react-native",
      "react-native/**",
      "dayjs",
      "dayjs/**"
    ]
  }
```